# A better way to tag-search without using a giant tag-exclusion list?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-search

I am generally pretty quiet on SO, but I do search through questions a lot to see if I can help out.

I frequent the [C++] tag and am generally looking for questions related to the language and not extensions, API's, etc.  So in the end, my tag search begins including a lot of tag exclusions.  For example:

```
[c++] -[boost] -[opencv] -[dll] -[ccombobox] -[boost-regex] -[java] -[linux] -[ubuntu] -[amazon-s3] -[qt] -[matlab] -[rogue-wave] -[simd]
```

My question is: Is there a better way to search like this?  Possibly tag combination saving or pre-existing tag groups?

Comment: Currently: no. But it would be a good feature request to add a `exclude ignored tags` filter.

Comment: I think that `intags:mine` use both, favorites and ignored tag, to create a search list.

Comment: Perhaps this could be accomplished with a new feature in the custom search parameters. Tags. `tags:1` where tags: simply indicated the total count of tags. I don't think it would be too hard on the db to query like this either, so it shouldn't cause undue load.

Comment: `intags:mine` includes favorite tags and excludes ignored tags. When you type `intags:mine` in the search on the right side then all tags that have been included and excluded are listed.

Comment: @TravisJ: It seems like that would exclude e.g. [c++] [syntax] [templates], which is probably not desirable at all.

Comment: _“When you type `intags:mine` in the search_ **then** _on the right side all tags that have been included and excluded are listed.”_ This is what my sentence from above should have been…